# Free tool to convert ArcGIS layer package (*.lpk) to shapefile (*.shp)?

Tags: shapefile, layer-package

I have received a [*.lpk file](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisexplorer/900/en/add_arcgis_layers.htm) from Esri's ArcGIS platform that I would like to convert to a shapefile.

How can I do this, using only free software?

Comment: The lpk I recently attempted to open was a [7z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7z) compressed file, it offers very good compression but it isn't possible to open it on the default zip client on Windows 7 64 bit, [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) is a good Windows client for opening it. The currently available ArcGIS Explorer Build 1750 also fails to open this lpk, I hope the new Build 2500 which is should be available soon addresses this.

Comment: I have same problem, how you convert lpk to shp ? @Zach

Answer (score 34):

I don't think I've ever seen this officially documented, but a layer package is a zip file that contains a .lyr file and a file geodatabase. You can change the file extension to .zip, unzip it and then, if the layer package was create with 10, read/export features to shapefiles using [OGR](http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_filegdb.html).

Comment: Per @seumas above, note that this currently appears to use `7z`, not `zip`.

Answer (score 3):

Just install 7zip --> Right Click --> Extract to...

Answer (score 1):

LPK is a proprietary layer package (zip file) made by ESRI.
I stand corrected. See Zach's answer
Converting to shape file is another matter.
If the originating data is gdb then the resulting lpk unzips to a file gdb.
HTH

Answer (score 1):

### Using Layer & Map Packages outside of ArcGIS

#### Hopeful

Find someone with ArcMap/Pro to use [Feature Class to Shapefile](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-shapefile.htm) geoprocessing tools on the file-gdb contents.

#### Self serve

Layer and Map packages (`.lpkx`, `.mpkx`) are a zipped up archive of an Esri file-geodatabase and some metadata to help with style and symbol display. For a non-Esri product:

- Use [7zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) or similar to extract into it’s raw components.
- Drill down until you find `something.gdb`. This is the data. Everything else is for ArcGIS and can be ignored. There will be more than one copy of the same thing in different folders. You only need one. The naming convention goes like:

  - `p12` is designed for ArcGIS Pro 1.2
  - `p20` is designed for ArcGIS Pro 2.0
  - etc.
- Use [global-mapper](/questions/tagged/global-mapper), [qgis](/questions/tagged/qgis), [GDAL Utilities](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/270148/what-are-gdal-utilities), etc. to read the file-gdb contents and export to shapefile or something else your other software can use.

As another option, there's probably way to use a free public [arcgis-online](/questions/tagged/arcgis-online) account to upload, add to web map, and then extract the data.

*nb: credit to @derekswingley for the [critical insight](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/12978/108) of this answer.*

Answer (score -5):

In case you have ArcGIS installed, then open the LPK layer file in ArcMap. Select the layer and right click and then click "Data" menu item and then click "Export Data" sub-menu-item. You can select the format of the output file.

Comment: ArcGIS is not a free tool. But if you have access to ArcGIS, this is a valid approach.

Answer (score -5):

1. Open ArcMap
2. Open ArcCatalog
3. On ArcCatalog, navigate to your file and right click it
4. Click "Unpack"
5. Your data should be displayed in ArcMap
6. Go to the table of contents in ArcMap and right click on your file
7. Select, Data>Export Data and save it as a shapefile with the desired extent, projection.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question "How can I do this, using only free software?" I suppose the asker doesn't have Arcgis.This type of answer has already been given below and has collected downvotes...